# Add parameter to use of middle in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Title: Laravel 10 middleware not accepting additional parameter in handle() function

Question:
I am trying to add an extra parameter to a middleware in Laravel, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here is the code for the middleware's `handle()` method:

```php
class checkUserRoles
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @param string $requiredRole
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $requiredRole): Response
    {
        // Middleware logic goes here
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this middleware in my web routes as follows:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['login', "checkUserRoles:ExemptionViewer"]], function () {
    Route::get('/exemptions', [\App\Http\Controllers\ExemptionController::class, 'index']);
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\checkUserRoles::handle(), 2 passed in and exactly 3 expected
```

What could be causing this error? How can I properly pass the required additional parameter to the middleware? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you register the middleware?

Comment: I registered the middleware in Kernal.php  as web route middleware

Comment: Thanks Kavan but I still get the sam error

Comment: Do you add the name for middleware in $routeMiddleware?